# Wrong TextView display in constraintlayout when anysize

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I dont know if this is a bug but if you try this layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dani.constraint.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duo aperiri eruditi cu, lorem assum pro eu. Eos ea nostrum detraxit, ne etiam iisque pro. Melius ceteros eu vel, per aliquip habemus at. Vix wisi utinam regione eu. At qui ipsum choro, et primis periculis eos. Putant aperiam mea ad, id mei prompta denique, velit voluptatibus sit ea. Discere accusam an quo."
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The text is not displayed correctly. I thought the expected behaviour would be like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dani.constraint.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duo aperiri eruditi cu, lorem assum pro eu. Eos ea nostrum detraxit, ne etiam iisque pro. Melius ceteros eu vel, per aliquip habemus at. Vix wisi utinam regione eu. At qui ipsum choro, et primis periculis eos. Putant aperiam mea ad, id mei prompta denique, velit voluptatibus sit ea. Discere accusam an quo." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result as in the relativelayout without setting padding to the parent? I'm using `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug and was fixed in alpha 5 -- you need to update to a more recent version of ConstraintLayout (alpha 6 just got released)

> com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha6